# How to print on same line and NOT overwrite old text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to output multiple things on the same line using python3's `print()` function.

What I've done is the following:

```
import sys, requests, serial, json

serPort = "/dev/tnt0"
serBaud = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(serPort, serBaud)

while True:
    scannerData = ser.read_until(b"\r").decode("utf-8")
    print(scannerData, end='')
```

What I expect to end up with when I send `hello world!\rbye` to the serial port is `hello world!bye`, but what I get is `byelo world!`

Without the `end=''` argument the print will add a newline and with the argument it will overwrite the previous output which is not what I want.

How to print on the same line WITHOUT resetting the cursor to the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\r` is carriage **return** which places "the cursor" at the beginning of the line.

If you don't want to actually perform a carriage return don't include it in the input:

```
print(scannerData.replace('\r', ''), end='')
```